# Compiler Flags for Mixing ARC and Non-ARC Code are ignored

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I am guess this is a simple one but I can't figure it out:

I got three files in my project that are not ARC compatible with the linker flag `-fno-obj-arc` set in Build Phases.

However the flags are ignored as far as I can tell. The compiler still complains about sending retain and release to objects.

I am using Xcode 4.2 with ARC enabled for the project. The classes are from MGSplitView.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried cleaning and deleting the "derived data" for your project?

Comment: Thanks for this tip, didn't know that cleaning doesn't delete the derived data. I'm sure that I entered the flag a few times correctly and building failed anyway....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your compiler flag is `-fno-obj-arc`. It is missing a `c` in `objc`.

It's `-fno-objc-arc`.

Hope this helps you.